# Oracle - Database state saving and then reverting

Tags: oracle11g, snapshot

I am currently porting some code from a big-endian to a little-endian system (Linux x86_64) which interacts with an Oracle database.

I am trying to make sure that the data is not messed up because of endian-difference, type changes (long is 8 bytes in 64-bit archs) etc.
Unfortunately I have just one database.

So when I want to compare the output of the old and the new code, I can't because they connect to the same DB!

I am not an Oracle person, so I am looking for some solution where I can in sequence:

1. Ask Oracle to remember the database state (millions of records) at a point-in-time.
2. Run the big-endian code.
3. For each column in each table, collect stats like average, max, min, stddev.
4. Ask Oracle to revert to the saved state.
5. Run the little-endian code.
6. For each column in each table, collect stats like average, max, min, stddev.

And then compare data from 3 and 6.

Granted, this wouldn't be as good as row-by-row comparison, but given the volume of data, this seems to be an acceptable solution.

Is this possible in Oracle without too much resource utilization (like adding new disks, because thats a lot of red-tape and takes too much time).

Thanks!

Comment: Is is safe to assume that the code you need to run spans multiple transactions so that you cannot simply issue a `ROLLBACK` to return to the saved state? Is flashback logging enabled?

Comment: Yes, the code is spilt into multiple modules and the modules themselves start and end multiple transactions. So a global rollback will not work. I need to check with the DBA on flashback logging, anyway I can check that myself?

Comment: If you can query the `v$database` table, `select flashback_on from v$database`

Comment: No @JustinCave, FLASHBACK_ON is 'NO' when I ran that query. Is it easy to turn that option on? Thanks for your responses!

Comment: It is relatively easy to enable.  It does require rebooting the database and it does generate additional logging that will generally require more space in the Flashback Recovery Area (i.e. more disk space).  You'd also have to ensure that the database is in `ARCHIVELOG` mode if it is not already.

Comment: I will explore this option. Thanks!